# How to select top 5 rows in current month from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm going to select top 5 product in this month from `order_log` where `id` and `date` equal to the columns in `order_db`. Because each order can be more than 1 product. It's a bit complicate to tell so please see my sample below.

**order_db**

```
+------+------+---------------------+
|od_id | p_id |     od_dtime        |
+------+------+---------------------+
|  1   |   1  | 2014-10-01 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
|  2   |   2  | 2014-10-01 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
|  3   |   3  | 2014-10-02 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
|  4   |   4  | 2014-10-02 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
|  5   |   5  | 2014-10-03 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
.
.
+------+------+---------------------+
|  10  |  10  | 2014-10-31 00:00:00 |
+------+------+---------------------+
```

**order_log**

```
+-------+------+
| pl_id | p_id |
+-------+------+
|   1   |  5   |
+-------+------+
|   2   |  5   |
+-------+------+
|   3   |  5   |
+-------+------+
|   4   |  2   |
+-------+------+
|   5   |  1   |
+-------+------+
.
.
.
+-------+------+
|   10  |  1   |
+-------+------+
```

So I need to count the `product_id` where date is in current month from `od_dtime` of `order_db`. I wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM order_log WHERE p_id IN 
(SELECT p_id FROM order_db WHERE month(bk_dtime)='10')
```

After running this query, I expect :

**Top 5 order of month 10 are :**

1. Product 3 (3 orders)
2. Product 1 (2 orders)
3. Product 2 (1 order)

**for the product name I don't have a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the top 5 rows from the database you can use the following sql query.

for eg: you have a table having some attributes including the time-stamp attribute and you wish to order in descending order of time

```
SELECT * FROM  table_name where acc_id='2' order by time desc limit 0 , 5
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer is too far from reality.

Comment: please correct me where I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.